# How to model the dialogue between users in a UML class diagram?

Tags: architecture, uml, analytics, class-diagram, system-design

I need to show a dialog between two different users on a UML class diagram, on a specific Topic where both entities can exchange an unlimited number of messages.
That is, now I actually have 3 entities: Topic/topic, user 1, user 2 (users of different semantics)
But I don't quite understand how to show it better from the point of view of displaying it on class structures and relationships. And specifically describe the exchange of messages on a specific topic, which is a separate entity

I was thinking towards association classes, but something tells me that this is not the direction I should be thinking in. Therefore, I want to get a more specific solution to the problem

Comment: message exchange is shown in a SD, not a CD

Comment: I second the suggestion of qwerty_so. Anyway, the minimum you should do is showing the diagram you have done so far as your attempt, possibly with explanation, why you made those design decisions. Hint: while describing to someone else what and why have you done, you often come up with what is wrong in your design and how can it be better (provided you know respective tools/notation standards). It's a known phenomenon used in the rubber duck technique.